# Table styling issue - column width

Tags: html, css

Here I provided [jssfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf6GR/)

How it looks now:
[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

This is made through table and div with border and negative margins, and works really unpredictable in different browsers.

It should be one table, with three small menu columns on top, and below them 100% table width column with content. But in fiddle it works in different way, help me to fix that.

CSS:

```
#main_box{
    width:60%;
    box-sizing:border-box;   

}
table#menu_table{
    position:relative;
     width:100%;
     border-collapse: collapse;

}
td.menu_item{

   width: 10%; 
    border:solid 1px green;
}
tr#content_row{
    width:100%;
}
td#content{
 border:solid 1px green;
```

Comment: Why are you building it using a table, versus `<div>`s? This doesn't look like data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colspan`. As you are you are yousing three column, use `colspan="3"`

```
<td colspan="3">Table Cell</td>
```

Just replace your code with this:
See this: http://jsfiddle.net/wf6GR/1/

```
    <td class="menu_item">publish</td>
    <td class="menu_item"> edit</td>
    <td class="menu_item"> delete </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='content_row'>
   <td id="content" colspan="3">
       The aid issue in in the 1960s 
After the Second World War, Sweden’s ﬁrst sense of afﬁliation was with the other Nordic 
countries. Its foreign policy was characterized  a will to decrease super power tensions by urging for patience and caution. Foreign Minister Östen Undén emphasised 
the importance of strengthening international law and thereby backing up the rights of 
small states. At the same time, Sweden was not believed to play a signiﬁcant role in 
world politics and should not take side in any important security .  


            </td>
        </tr>

     </table>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `colspan` and set up your table like this:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zSXq/)**

```
<table border="1" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="">
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But using a `table` for this is a bit wrong - you could have a look at **[jQueryTools - Tabs](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/)**

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer too, because your advice about tabls is actually more useful than relative answer!

Answer (score 0):

Append another `<td>` tag on the menu items then apply `colspan="4"` on the `#content`.

You can add a class to the appended `<td>` tag so that you can style that to `border: 0;`

View example JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4mbfn/).